# Entity Framework Namesapce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

I have a preexisting project, and I'm trying to set it up on a different computer with a new local db called (localdb)\StevensDB , which is supposed to mimic the one that the project was previously using. I have changed the connection string in the Web.config file to match

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\StevensDB
previously
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\V11.0
```

However I'm getting this error and I don't quite understand where it's coming from
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'StevensDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image: This is the connected database]

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: Where are you getting that error ? That error has nothing to do with you changing just  the connection string.

Comment: I'm getting that error in every instance of calling StevensDB, so for example 
`
    public WorkOrderModel(StevensDB dbContext, int userID)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.userID = userID;
    }
`

Comment: Did you regenerate your EDMX again after changing your conn string ? You should not be unless there is a db schema change.

Comment: I haven't regenerated it no

Comment: I fixed the errors by regenerating the EDMX, but I am getting a casting error:
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal' to type 'StevensHub.Models.User'.